# Drawing rectangle with given color

Tags: kivy

What should I do in below code to make the rectangle background color different than background? I belive the problem here is with `ScrollView` because when I change it for `RelativeLayout` or `BoxLayout` then I can draw the rectangle.

```
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
import copy

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1280')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '720')
Config.write()

kv = '''

Main:

    ScrollView:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0.2, 0.745, 0.745, 1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        StackLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (0.2, 0, 0.745, 1)

            height: max(self.minimum_height, root.height)
            size_hint_y: None

'''

class Main(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.touch_down_pos = [0, 0]

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):

        self.touch_down_pos = copy.deepcopy(touch)
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud['rectangle'] = Rectangle(pos=(touch.x, touch.y), size=(0, 0))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):

        touch.ud['rectangle'].size = (touch.x - self.touch_down_pos.x, touch.y - self.touch_down_pos.y)
        return super(Main, self).on_touch_move(touch)

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class BajotApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BajotApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `Color` to your `on_touch_down()` method:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    self.touch_down_pos = copy.deepcopy(touch)
    with self.canvas:
        Color(0,1,0,1)
        touch.ud['rectangle'] = Rectangle(pos=(touch.x, touch.y), size=(0, 0))
    return super(Main, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```